# Model não carrega CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, apache

estou tentando fazer um Model funcionar, ele funciona em MAC com MAMP PRO, mas em ubuntu com Apache2 ele não funciona.

models/users_model.php

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

Class Users_model extends CI_Model {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }
```

controllers/verifylogin.php

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class VerifyLogin extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('users_model', '', TRUE);
    }
```

Ao fazer o login em **cms.local/admin/login** ele redireciona para **admin/verifylogin**

Nessa tela ele dispara esse erro:

> An Error Was Encountered
>
> Unable to locate the model you have specified: Users_model

**CodeIgniter 3**

Comment: Os outros model carregam certo?

Comment: Resolvido, no CodeIgniter 3 os arquivos tem que ser no modo "capitalize", ex: **Verifylogin.php, models/Users_model.php**

Comment: @rray nenhum model carregava, porque estava com lowercase os arquivos.

Comment: Coloca isso como resposta, se achar o link da documentação que fala isso fica melhor.

Comment: Sim, até poderia postar a resposta, porém o erro não é no CodeIgniter, sim no Ubuntu, porque no Mac com MAMP Pro funciona. Que estranho.

Comment: Mas o nome da classe não esta diferente do arquivo? [link da documentação](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/models.html)

Comment: Não, não estava, porém no Mac eu usava sem o **_model** tranquilo, apenas **models/users.php** e a classe como **Users** em **verifylogin.php**, irei reportar esse bug, também vou comparar as versões do PHP dos dois.